# Auth0: Including custom fields in getAccessTokenSilently and using them in rules/actions

Tags: reactjs, auth0

We are using Auth0 SDK and trying to include a custom field during the login process. The purpose is to be able to inject dynamic params into payload from rules. Client is a react.js app and we use @auth0/auth0-react library. Noticed that getAccessTokenSilently is extensible to include custom params:

```
const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently({
        audience: 'myaudience',
        scope: 'read:read_users',
        'foo': 'bar'
    });
```

The question is, how we get access to foo=bar from inside the rules triggers?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To access custom fields in access token, you need Auht0 Auth pipeline rules. To trigger rule you need to pass additional option `ignoreCache: true` i.e.

```
const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently({
    ignoreCache: true,
    audience: 'myaudience',
    scope: 'read:read_users',
    customClaim1: 'MyUserId',
    customClaim2: 'MyPreference'
});
```

In Auht0 Auth pipeline rules, access these custom fields in `context.request.query` and assign in accessToken as shown below:

```
function (user, context, callback) {
  const namespace = 'http://rules/customClaims';
  const customClaim1 = (context.request.query || {}).customClaim1;
  const customClaim2 = (context.request.query || {}).customClaim2;  

  let accessTokenClaims = context.accessToken || {};

  accessTokenClaims[`${namespace}/customClaim1`] = customClaim1; 
  accessTokenClaims[`${namespace}/customClaim2`] = customClaim2;  

  context.accessToken = accessTokenClaims;
  return callback(null, user, context);
}
```

You can pass and access any custom field in rule. In your case simply replace `customClaim1: 'MyUserId'` with `'foo': 'bar'`